# How to implement UIPageControl from UIViewController

Tags: iphone

I have 3 pdf file for 1 chapter like "pdf_chapter_1_page_1.pdf","pdf_chapter_1_page_2.pdf","pdf_chapter_1_page_3.pdf". In first chapter we have 3 pdf file. I want to display these 3 pdf file in iPhone. When user will open application he will be on 1st page of chapter and whenever he will drag either horizontal or vertical next pages of same chapter will be loaded.

And I am trying make it with UIPageControl. Is it good idea ? If yes how would i implement it from UIviewController class. I don't want to use it on my MainWindow.xib screen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go through the below blog posts.

[PageControl Example in iPhone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/)

The below post use the images for pagination, you could display your pdf (possibly by using UIWebView) in the same way.

[How to build UIScrollView with page control](http://www.xprogress.com/post-53-how-to-build-uiscrollview-with-page-control/)

Comment: I have clicked answer right but i am not sure it will work. It seems to to work. I am still working to get it done.